# C++ --> Matlab -- mexFunction template

Tags: mex

I have a rookie request to make, but i'll be very grateful for your help:
Can someone write for me a brief mexFunction template, which I can add the a cpp script, and have the mexFunction inputs and outputs interact with the cpp's functions?

mexFunction(output array, input array)
{

*actions to use the C++ functions* // a brief explanation 
*actions to extract the resulting output* // a brief explanation

}

I don't quite get C++ syntax yet, and I don't find any of the tutorials out there very helpful (I did the obvious google search:).
I'm trying to evaluate a certain C++ code with matlab, and im kind of in the dark here.

You help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are enough resources available to get started using MEX functions. Yet you wanted to straight away find some answers / links / codes / materials from here (fair idea - sadly you may get down votes). To answer you and get to a good start ::

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

Only **one data type** in MEX : mxArray  (In some ways, this makes life easier, as it reduces the number of data types to you need to
remember, but it does mean that you need to be careful, and not make any assumptions about the format
of the contents of the array.)

To access the data within an mxArray, you need to get a pointer to it

```
   double *a;
   a = mxGetPr(phrs[0]);
```

To check if a given mxArray contains double precision floats, use:

```
if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0])) {
mexErrMsgTxt("Input should be double.\n");
}
```

To give an idea, instead of just referring to some links, I tried to explain you. Hope it helped.

Some references:

[How to create mex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5026/MATLAB-MEX-files)

[Kind of complete reference (pdf file)](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ee264/Fall11/cmex.pdf)

Comment: Thank for your references, but you state there yourselft that familiarity with C++ is assumed, and as I said, that's not the case with me.